# How get request user data in django rest to representation function

Tags: django-rest-framework

I need to access `request.user` in `to_representation` function, I tried `self.context['request']` but `self.context` is empty dictionary. Is there anyway to access `request.user` or any way that I can push this data to this function?

```
def to_representation(self, obj):
    print(self.context)

#output is an empty dictionary {}
```

**UPDATE**

```
class RetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        uid = kwargs.get('uid')
        try:
            item = self.model.nodes.get(uid=uid)
        except Exception as e:
            # error response
        serializer = self.serializer_class(item)
        return HttpSuccessResponse(SuccessResponse(serializer.data).to_json(), status=status.HTTP_200_OK).send()


class TopicRetrieveView(single_result.RetrieveView):
    model = Topic
    serializer_class = topic.TopicSerializer
```

Comment: can you add your view implementation where you use your serializer? if you use one of the rest framework's views, the context should be correctly set. So my guess is the problem would be in that area.

Comment: @EnthusiastMartin Is this update fine?

Comment: Thanks to @EnthusiastMartin I found my error I need to use self.get_serializer() inested of self.serializer_class

Comment: Yes, i was just writing a response about that. Have fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ALL CODES are from django rest framwork Generic views [generic.py](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py)**

`serializer_class` is attribute we set in class definition or we need to override `get_serializer_class` function. It will handle in this function:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    """
    Return the class to use for the serializer.
    Defaults to using `self.serializer_class`.

    You may want to override this if you need to provide different
    serializations depending on the incoming request.

    (Eg. admins get full serialization, others get basic serialization)
    """
    assert self.serializer_class is not None, (
        "'%s' should either include a `serializer_class` attribute, "
        "or override the `get_serializer_class()` method."
        % self.__class__.__name__
    )

    return self.serializer_class
```

`get_serializer_class` will used in `get_serializer` function:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Return the serializer instance that should be used for validating and
    deserializing input, and for serializing output.
    """
    serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
    kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

and `context` will fill by `get_serializer_context` function.

```
def get_serializer_context(self):
    """
    Extra context provided to the serializer class.
    """
    return {
        'request': self.request,
        'format': self.format_kwarg,
        'view': self
    }
```

So correct usage is `serializer = self.get_serializer(item)` because it will use `serializer_class` for serializing item and fill `context` with extra information that may be helpful. `serializer = self.serializer_class(item)` can be used for just serializing item with no more extra information.